# jQuery code to have multiple/clickable Graphical icons on screen

Tags: jquery, icons

There's a lot of example code out there but I'm not able to find anything that fits the bill exactly. I should explain that I am relatively new to jQuery coding, or HTML for that matter.

I need to create code to display a number of icons (squares) containing graphical content. The icons need to be clickable and the click event captured. The icons themselves should be displayable in (possibly) an invisible grid of 8 x 10 icons, but as the screen is resizable it would be handy if this was dynamic when the screen size was changed. The icons need to possibly change colour when clicked and I may need an option to show some icons in a disabled mode.

Has anyone come across any code which partially fits this requirement?. 
I'll keep looking but would be oblige if anything springs to mind.

Regards to all.

Jason

Comment: Do you have a sketch/screenshot of how this is supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="asquare"><img src="/.." /></div>
<div class="asquare"><img src="/.." /></div>
...

$('.asquare').click(function(){
   $(this).css({background-color:'red'});
});
```

Something along those lines..?

Just read around some of the basic jQuery functions, it's all really easy to follow :)

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

note: if you want to animate colours, you need [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)